# JS Fetch: Is there a way to pass on a table name with a fetch reequest?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, fetch

I have two tables, one for users, one for todos and I use the following code to get all todos when the todo button is click. I want to use the same function to get all users.

index.html:

```
    displayItems() {
      fetch('/getItems',{
        method: "get",
      }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
      }).then((data)=>{
        this.items = data
      });
    }
```

app.js:

```
app.get('/getItems', (req,res)=>{      
  db.getDB().collection(tableName).find({}).toArray((err,documents)=>{
    if(err)
      console.log(err);
    else {
      console.log(documents);
      res.json(documents);
    }
  });
});
```

This works fine as long as I set `tableName` in app.js but then I have to write separate functions to get the items from the two different tables.

Is there a way to pass on the table name when I call fetch in my index.html depending on which button was clicked?

Comment: It's just a string pass in a param and map it with a value in stored object, but try to be careful not to expose collection names in endpoints/urls if you wanted to pass it in request.

Comment: If you're using mongoose then you can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702041/nodejs-mongodb-dynamic-collection-name but do not pass-in exact same collection names in request which might not be an issue but just think why would you expose all your collection names in urls :-).

Comment: Generally speaking, it's better off to write separate RESTful API endpoints on the server side to query different tables/collections as not to expose the actual collection name. One URL gettodos for todo, and another URL, maybe getUsers for Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you send a parameter to your `displayItems` function and send it as a `get paramater` like

```
displayItems(tableName) {
  fetch('/getItems?table='+tableName,{
    method: "get",
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((data)=>{
    this.items = data
  });
}
```

and then you can access it on your server side using `req.query` like

```
app.get('/getItems', (req,res)=>{      
  db.getDB().collection(req.query.table).find({}).toArray((err,documents)=>{
    if(err)
      console.log(err);
    else {
      console.log(documents);
      res.json(documents);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @JonathanSchiffner , use backticks ( the key below the escape key) if you want to use template literals. normal single quotations will not work..